# What is the usage of .* into sql

Tags: sql

I review an stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT Mold.*, Cat.IdMope
            INTO #tmpMolde
            FROM proove.tmpMolde Mold
        LEFT JOIN pere.srcMaquina Cat ON Mold.maq= Cat.maq;
```

As you an see it say `Mold.*` but I really don´t know what is the usage of `.*` can anyone explain me? Regards

Comment: This is adding all columns from the Mold table to a temporary table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means all fields from that table. Note: This is bad practice and should be replaced with an explicit list of columns. This helps with robustness and indeed performance so is worth doing.

Comment: Yes, see answers in this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful